# Alarm code raises invalidoperation exception in Background task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-phone, alarm

In my windows phone 8 app, I am using a ScheduledTaskAgent to do some code on schedule basis.
During the task code, I am running an alarm at start immediately. I am using below code to do Alarm

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm("Test Alarm");
alarm.Content = "My Test alarm";
alarm.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
alarm.ExpirationTime = alarm.BeginTime.AddSeconds(5);
alarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Assets/Beep.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

// Add the reminder to the ScheduledActionService 
ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
```

At scheduledactionservice add place, i am getting below exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: BNS Error: The API can only be called from foreground app.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a scheduled task from a background agent, only from the app itself. You need to schedule the alarm from your UI code.